# Как учесть месяцы при получение возраста человека?

Tags: javascript

console.log(getAge('11.07.2021') )

выводит один

но о факт ж нету еще одного года

```js
function getAge(birthDateString) {
    if (!birthDateString) throw new Error('Invalid date');
    
    const dateInstance = new Date(Date.parse(birthDateString));
    
    return new Date().getFullYear() - dateInstance.getFullYear();
}

console.log(getAge('11.07.2021') )
```

Comment: Наверное можно принять год человека за 365 дней и отталкиваться от дней

Comment: учтите еще то, что `11.07.2021` с точки зрения парсера дат это 7 ноября 2021. `getFullYear` возращает просто год, то есть в вашем примере получается  `2022-2021=1`

Comment: попробуйте использовать функцию `Date.getTime()` которая возращает количество миллисекунд с 01.01.1970..и уже их разницу смотрите, есть там год или нет.

Answer (score 1):

Основная суть моего алгоритма в следующем:

- Вычисляем разницу с сегодняшним днём в миллисекундах
- Создаём дату на основе этих миллисекунд
- Дело в том что 0 миллисекунд - это 1970-ый год 1-ый месяц и 1-ый день в JS. Потому нам надо это всё вычесть в конце, чтобы точно узнать разницу в годах, месяцах и днях

Я в этом случае откинул часть с часами т.к. обычно на них не обращают внимания, но при желании можете его включить

Плюс такого подхода в том, что не нужно думать о високосных годах, о том что в каждом месяце ровно 30 дней и другие факторы, которе могут повлиять на тоность вычислений

Сам код:

```js
function getAge(birthDateString) {
  if (!birthDateString) throw new Error('Invalid date');

  const now = new Date();
  now.setMilliseconds(0);
  
  const [nowHours, nowMinutes, nowSeconds] = [now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds()].map(num => `${num}`.padStart(2, '0'));
  const [day, month, year] = birthDateString.split('.');
  const birthDate = new Date(`${year}-${month}-${day}T${nowHours}:${nowMinutes}:${nowSeconds}`);
  
  const diff = new Date(now.getTime() - birthDate.getTime());

  const age = diff.toISOString().split('T')[0];
  const [fullYear, fullMonth, fullDay] = age.split('-').map(str => +str);

  return `Age is ${fullYear - 1970} year(s) ${fullMonth - 1} month(s) ${fullDay - 1} day(s)`;
}

console.log(getAge('11.06.2021'));
console.log(getAge('11.07.2021'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getAge(birthDateString) {
    if (!birthDateString) throw new Error('Invalid date');

    const dateInstance = new Date(Date.parse(birthDateString));

    return ((new Date().getTime() - dateInstance.getTime()) / (30*24*60*60*1000)).toFixed()
    /*
    30 - Дней
    24 - Часов
    60 - Минут
    60 - Сек
    1000 миллСек
    */
    
    /*
      Еще кстати 1 на консоле означает Января
    */
}

console.log(getAge('1.07.2021'))
console.log(getAge('Jan 7 2021'))
```

Comment: и что такое ваш код вернет?

Comment: @teran `Как учесть месяцы при получение возраста человека?`
Вернет возраст в месяцах. [Минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) на консоле)